# Overriding node module method that uses a local variable (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a package (node module) which has some methods, but unfortunately they are constructed in a strange way.
All methods refer to a variable which only exists inside the package (local var).

So for example:

```
var theVar = {};

module.exports.foo = function() {
theVar.someMethod();
}
```

Well, I would like to override some of these methods in my new lib, but cannot do it because of theVar. Its value of course points to the old stuff, but I need to make it point to a new object.

Could someone tell me how to override such methods? Is this even possible in JS?

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT

So just to make sure I understand this correctly:

theVar is actually defined like this:

```
var theVar = module.exports.theVar = {....}
```

However, all the methods of the module use it like:

```
exports.func = function() {
   theVar.method()  // and not exports.theVar.method()
}
```

So this means, theVar cannot be changed, right? I could only change exports.theVar.

Comment: if you define your own "theVar" and then "eval('mod.foo='+mod.foo)", it will re-close the function body code with the new "theVar". you break all closures like that, so make sure "theVar" is all it needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `theVar` gets `return`'ed somewhere as a whole (its reference, so to speak), then yes, you can just overwrite any *method* / *property* contained by it (if those *properties* were not made *imuteable* by `Object.freeze()` or other methods).

If that *object* is not made *public* somewhere, by passing its reference around, then no, there is no way in ECMAscript to break into an *unknown* context. In other words, you can't access a *closured* variable from anywhere, but a *child context*.

Comment: OK I see, thanks Andy. I guess it is closured, the module just uses it internally and doesn't export it anywhere. So then I'll have to copy the code..